# Add data to ImageView to retrieve later with onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have an layout with an `ImageView`, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is used in my `RecyclerView`. Here is the adapter for the layout:

```
public class LayoutAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LayoutAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;

    private List<Data> data;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    public LayoutAdapter(Context context, List<Data> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.main_layout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Data data = data.get(position);

        // TODO: bind data.getUser() to image
        // data.getUser() returns the User model object

        // starts new activity, need to pass image getUser() data to the activity
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

What I need to do (as commented in the code), is add data to the `ImageView` so that I can pass that data to the `UserActivity` when the image is clicked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can set image source like what you used to do.

Second, you can pass `Data` from your activity to `UserActivity` like this:

1. Edit your `Data` class, implement `Serializable`

   public class Data implements Serializable{
2. in `onClick` method

   final Data data = data.get(position);

   ```
       // TODO: bind data.getUser() to image
       // data.getUser() returns the User model object

       // starts new activity, need to pass image getUser() data to the activity
       holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserActivity.class);
               intent .putExtra("data", data);
               context.startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
   ```
3. in `UserActivity` you can retreive it

   `Data receivedData = (Data) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");`